# Use Stored Procedure To Create View

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I want to create a stored procedure which I can pass a parameter to for the database name and it will create a view for me.

I am just trying to save some time by not writing the same statement over and over and over for a create vew.

Below is my syntax - how could this be modified to run in a stored procedure accepting a parameter?

```
Alter View dbo.ForceClose
As
SELECT DISTINCT(SessionID) As CountofSessionID
FROM Database1      
WHERE forceClosed IS NOT NULL 
AND stillOpen IS NULL
and (userName is not null or userName IN ('JJones', 'MHill', 'RMort'))
Go
```

And in the stored procedure accept a parameter as the database name (I know this isn't valid just trying to show an example) -- call the stored procedure like so

```
exec dbo.Procedure 'DBName'
```

And the stored procedure would then look like

```
@DBName varchar(100)
Select blah blah FROM' + @DBName + '
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use a Stored Procedure to Create a View

Comment: I got that part, but I don't understand is what you want to pass to it?

Comment: a parameter to use as the database name.  Something like create in the Stored procedure a variable @DBName varchar(100) and pass this variable to the stored procedure for the database name.  I'll edit my original post to hope make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ForceClose
(
    @DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(255)

    @SQL='SELECT DISTINCT(SessionID) As CountofSessionID
    FROM ['+@DBNAME+'].[SCHEMA].[TABLE_NAME]
    WHERE forceClosed IS NOT NULL 
    AND stillOpen IS NULL
    and (userName is not null or userName IN (''JJones'', ''MHill'', ''RMort''))'
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

And you can run it by:

```
EXEC ForceClose <DBNAME>
```

**With the View:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ForceClose
(
    @DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(255)

    @SQL='CREATE VIEW VIEW_'+DBNAME+' AS SELECT DISTINCT(SessionID) As CountofSessionID
    FROM ['+@DBNAME+'].[SCHEMA].[TABLE_NAME]
    WHERE forceClosed IS NOT NULL 
    AND stillOpen IS NULL
    and (userName is not null or userName IN (''JJones'', ''MHill'', ''RMort''))'
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

And you can run it by:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_<DBNAME>
```

Comment: Where do I put the name for the view I am creating?

Comment: I added second version with the View.

Comment: I hardcoded the View name as "VIEW_"and dbname.
Remember to change schema and table name's.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what the create view is doing; the basic premise you want is dynamic SQL (and there are lots of good questions and answers on the subject. A really simple answer would be

```
declare @myparameter nvarchar(100)= 'master'

declare @myquery nvarchar(1000)

select @myquery = 'select * from ' + @myparameter + '.dbo.sysdatabases'

select @myquery 

exec sp_executeSQL @myquery
```

Running this returns a list of the databases on your server.

If you want to create a view; would you not need to know the table to query? The basic technique is the same

```
declare @myparameter nvarchar(100)= 'master'

declare @myquery nvarchar(1000)

select @myquery = 'Create View myschema.vw' + @myparameter + ' as select * from ' + @myparameter + '.dbo.sysdatabases'

select @myquery 
exec sp_executeSQL @myquery
```

If this is in an application the user permissions to do this would be very high for a general application; you might want to wrap it with an execute as permission to stop people doing too much damage.